# How to calculate the voltage of a DC motor?

Tags: electricity, voltage

I have a DC motor. But I don't know its voltage. If I connect with a 3.2V battery, then the motor rotates. Can I find the voltage of the motor from the rpm of the motor?

Comment: Why not measure it with a voltmeter? You should find that voltage of the motor terminals is the same as voltage of the battery that connects to those terminals.

Answer (score 0):

The EMF of a dc motor is given by $$E= \frac{NP\phi Z}{60A}$$where, E=EMF, N=Speed of rotation in RPM, P= Number of poles, Z= number of conductors in armature, A= Number of parallel paths. 
Assuming you know the other parameters in your motor, you can calculate the voltage required for a **specific RPM**.